# Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes gives perchtest/index.php Forbidden 403

Tags: php, .htaccess, perch

Throughout my website I use html, but want to incorporate a .php cms called perch. When trying to run the compatability test, I got a Forbidden 403. When I deactivated the .htacess it worked. After some time testing I have narrowed it down to this

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
```

When I comment it out, it works, but being ignorant on how htaccess fully works, I don't know what this is deactivating. What can I do to have this still activated and get my site to allow access to .php files. My htaccess code in full (sans page specific redirects) is below.

```
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteEngine on
AddType text/html .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
# Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes <-----
AddHandler server-parsed .html .htm

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on

# Your document html
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"

# Media: images, video, audio
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 2 weeks"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2 weeks"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2 weeks"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2 weeks"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 2 weeks"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 2 weeks"
  ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 2 weeks"

# CSS and JavaScript
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 0 seconds"
</IfModule>

# compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/js

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
# remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
```